# PHP checkbox mailer foreach error

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've made a form, wich gets the info for the checkboxes in it from a xml file. Now I want to mail that form with php, but I got an "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in mailer.php on line 8" error. Here's the checkbox part off my form, written in javascript:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
xmlhttp.open("GET","dehoek.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");

for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write('<input name="check[]" id="checkbox'+i+'" type="checkbox" value="'+(x[i].getElementsByTagName("naam")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)+'" /><label for="checkbox'+i+'">'+(x[i].getElementsByTagName("naam")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)+' &nbsp; €'+(x[i].getElementsByTagName("prijs")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)+' </label>');
}
```

And here's my php:

```
$aan =  $_POST['to']; 
$onderwerp =  "Bestelling"; 
$naam =  $_POST['naam']; 
$email =  $_POST['email']; 
$message =  "Producten:"; 

foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) { 
$check_msg .= "$value\n";
} 

$body =  "From: $naam\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message\n $check_msg"; 

echo  "Uw bestelling is succesvol verstuurd."; 
mail($aan,  $onderwerp, $body);
```

I hope someone of you know what's wrong with my code, because I really don't get it.

Thanks in advance,
Jan Thiemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently, in your PHP script, trying to read from `$_POST` :

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $value)
```

But your page is requesting using the [**HTTP GET**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods) method :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","dehoek.xml",false);
```

So, there is no such thing as `$_POST['check']` -- as `$_POST` only contains data when a page is requested using [**HTTP POST**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), and not GET.

If you request your page using and HTTP GET, you must, in your PHP script, read from [**`$_GET`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), and not [**`$_POST`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).